# Agrupación correcta de listas de listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np
n=2
p0 = 0.3
p1 = 0.7

# PARTE 1

#Se genera el proceso multiplicativo 
prob = [p0,p1]
p = [[p0,p1]]
while len(prob)<= pow(2,n-1):
    A = [z*p0 for z in prob]
    B = [z*p1 for z in prob]
    prob = A + B
    #Se guarda cada salida del ciclo en la lista p
    p.append(prob)
print(p,"\n")

# PARTE 2

#Se define el parámetro q
Q = np.arange(-2,3,1)

f = []
a = []
#Eleva cada entrada de p[i] a las potencias q = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2.
for q in Q:
    for i in p:
        #Genero nuevas probabilidades elevadas al exponente q
        P = [j**q for j in i]
        #Normalizo las nuevas probabilidades 
        M = P/sum(P)
        #Verifico que cada lista de probabilidad M, su suma sea igual a 1 
        print(M, sum(M), q)
        #Cantidades que necesito calcular
        F =[m*np.log(m) for m in M]
        A =[m*np.log(j) for m,j in zip(M,i) ]
        print(F,q)
        f.append(sum(F))
        #a.append(sum(A))
#print(f)
```

Contexto del programa:

Partiendo de dos valores de probabilidad: `[p0,p1]` quiero generar nuevas listas de probabilidad dado un numero de iteración `n`, a esto le llamo proceso multiplicativo y el ejemplo para `n = 2` es el siguiente:

> n = 1
>      [p0,p1]
>
> n = 2
>      [p0^2 , p0 p1, p1 p0, p1^2]

por lo tanto la lista grande de probabilidad `p` es

> p = [ [p0,p1], [p0^2 , p0 p1, p1 p0, p1^2] ]

Con `p` puedo calcular sin problema los valores que necesito, listas `F,A,f`, el problema es que al final obtengo una lista `f` de diez entradas, es decir; `len(f) = 10` cuando quisiera obtener `len(f) = 5` y cada `f[i]` que sea una lista de dos entradas. Esto lo necesito ya que quiero identificar cada `f[i]` con su valor de `q` que le corresponde y como tengo `5` valores de `q` necesito `len(f) = 5`.

Gracias por su atención!

Comment: Puedes escribir cual sera el resultado de f (de tamaño 5)? para comparar con lo que estoy obteniendo

Comment: Claro!

`f = [ [-0.43157722083182143, -0.86315444166364286],[-0.61086430205489339, -1.221728604109787] , [-0.69314718055994529, -1.3862943611198906] , [ -0.6108643020548935, -1.221728604109787] , [-0.43157722083182154, -0.86315444166364286] ]`

Comment: Gaby puedes entrar al chat? es que tengo una solución pero quiero discutirla antes contigo

Comment: Acaso `f` no es un producto escalar? algo como esto `np.dot(np.log(M),M)`

Comment: el problema es que cada entrada de `f` es a su vez un vector, por lo tanto el producto escalar sería entre `np.dot(np.log(M[i]),M[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo muy simple, agrega otra lista dentro del ciclo:

```
#Se define el parámetro q
Q = np.arange(-2,3,1)

f = []
a = []
#Eleva cada entrada de p[i] a las potencias q = -2, -1, 0, 1, 2.
for q in Q:
    temp = [] # agrega esta lista vacia
    for i in p:
        #Genero nuevas probabilidades elevadas al exponente q
        P = [j**q for j in i]
        #Normalizo las nuevas probabilidades
        M = P/sum(P)
        #Verifico que cada lista de probabilidad M, su suma sea igual a 1
        #print(M, sum(M), q)
        #Cantidades que necesito calcular
        F =[m*np.log(m) for m in M]
        A =[m*np.log(j) for m,j in zip(M,i) ]
        #print(F,q)
        temp.append(sum(F))
        #a.append(sum(A))
    f.append(temp)
print(f)
```

De esta forma `f` queda con 5 elementos, de acuerdo al tamaño de `Q`.

Comment: Gracias!!! si funciona de esta manera, :O